# HTTP.sys for HTTPS sniffing?

Tags: https, sniffing

so far I have read on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524901%28v=vs.90%29.aspx site that HTTP.sys actually deals with ssl requests.
my questions is ,

when I connecting to some https website 
can I retrieve its URL or maybe decrypted plain HTML from the HTTP.sys ?
if so how should I do that ? intercept the windows message to/from HTTP.sys ?
or it should be done in kernel module by hooking it both ways ?